# Move to the top function in google spreadsheets

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This function takes a currently selected cell or range and moves it to the top of the "list", so to speak.  Super useful in todo-lists.  Thanks to Brian P for the help!

```
function arrayShift(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var activeRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var toDoRange = sheet.getRange("A2:A9"); //the range of your todo list. 
  var howMany = activeRange.getNumRows();
  var topCell = activeRange.getRow();
  var rangeTop = toDoRange.getRow();
  var index = topCell - rangeTop; //gives the index of the selected cell
  var rangeArray = toDoRange.getValues();
  rangeArray.splice(index, howMany)

  if ( howMany == 1 ) {
    rangeArray.unshift(activeRange.getValues()[0]); 
  } else { // handle re-inserting multiple row values
    var values = activeRange.getValues();
    for ( var i = values.length - 1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
      rangeArray.unshift(values[i]);
    }
  }
  //Logger.log(rangeArray)
  toDoRange.clearContent();
  toDoRange.offset(0,0,rangeArray.length).setValues(rangeArray);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try...

```js
function arrayShift(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var activeRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var toDoRange = sheet.getRange("A2:A9"); //the range of your todo list. 
  var howMany = activeRange.getNumRows();
  var topCell = activeRange.getRow();
  var rangeTop = toDoRange.getRow();
  var index = topCell - rangeTop; //gives the index of the selected cell
  var rangeArray = toDoRange.getValues();
  rangeArray.splice(index, howMany)

  if ( howMany == 1 ) {
    rangeArray.unshift(activeRange.getValues()[0]); // "remove brackets"
  } else { // handle re-inserting multiple row values
    var values = activeRange.getValues();
    for ( var i = values.length - 1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
      rangeArray.unshift(values[i]);
    }
  }
  //Logger.log(rangeArray)
  toDoRange.clearContent();
  toDoRange.offset(0,0,rangeArray.length).setValues(rangeArray);
};
```

Comment: Thanks Brian!!  It works great!  I got the impression last time I posted that I should put the fixed code in the original question.  This seems weird like I'm taking credit?  Also, are there at mentions on stackoverflow?  Sorry for Newbness!

Comment: You can leave your original question / code next time. Only update with clarifications. Marking the questioned as answered / upvoting does show what to use instead as you suspected.

Comment: Oops!  Sorry Brian, don't know what the code used to be anymore.  No disrespect intended.  Will do that next time.  Thanks again for the help!!